# Button Up Action Bar not show when SearchView Opened in Navigation Drawer Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, drawer

I implement Drawer and Action Navigation Bar on the application. One of the ActionBar that I use is SearchView. And I have followed this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/. Now I'm trying to replace the Home button Drawer with Button Up SearchView current in the open state, and vice versa if searchView in a closed state. my case like this question> [How can I dismiss the Navigation Drawer to use the Back-home-icon button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660652/how-can-i-dismiss-the-navigation-drawer-to-use-the-back-home-icon-button) and I have followed someone who responded by using `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled (false); and getSupportActionBar (). setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`, but it does not seem to work. It is part of my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

and this is full code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this,SearchResultsActivity.class)));


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

so how fix it ? thanks